# How to achieve fountain looking falloff of spheres

Tags: physics

I am making lottery wheel with balls in it. I want to make animation looking like water fountain - so, from the bottom of wheel it pushes them to middle of wheel, then they fall a bit do the right or left.
[image]

Something like this fountain. I couldn't achieve this only by wind or vortex.[image]

Imagine those lines as paths of balls.
[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file, we will update it. Normally it is just the cause of wrong parameters. increase wind to e.g. 1000  - then you will see that they react to the wind. Decrease slowly until it is doing what you want. That's where experience hits. If you know what values to put in, you are faster. If you don't know you have to use try and error until it fits.

Comment: By giving an initial velocity to the balls, you could do that. Wind or vortex may not be the way to do it.

Comment: I added blend file. Thank you. Problem with wind is, if it is too strong it just pushes them to the top of wheel and they stay there like there is some sort of magnetic on top of wheel.
How do you mean about velocity? First time seeing this, do I need just to change object velocity or?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a real lottery bowl, the balls are blown up from a stream of air that is quite thin in diameter. If you are using the *Wind* object with default settings, it blows evenly across the whole area.

So you should set the *Falloff* to *Tube*, then you have to adjust *Max Distance* and for the diameter change *Radial* > *Max Distance*. The values depend a lot on the size of your objects and the look you want to achieve.

To help blow the balls to the outside I've added a *Force* object above with limited *Max Distance* to affect the balls as soon as the wind decreases. I've also set the weight of the balls quite low. The result looks like this:

[image]

[image: lottery]

Comment: Thank you! That's it. I will need to tweak controls a little so I can get wanted results.

Comment: @Radoon You're welcome. Of course there's room for tweaking and maybe instead of _Force_ you could use other force fields to get different results. I think the main thing is to use the limits of the force fields if you want to recreate certain effects.